# php set cookie expiry time

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting a cookie using php's setcookie and the expire value is set to 0.
However when I look at the cookie using developer tools 
it shows the below i.e the expires as 1970  . How do i make the expires time in the future but making the session expire when the browser is closed.

My security team is complaining of this as expired cookies.

[image]

Comment: From the docs `This is a Unix timestamp` so `0` seconds is 1970, setting a cookies date to the past causes it to go away when the session is closed. `How do i make the expires time in the future but making the session expire when the browser is closed. ` is 2 conflicting concepts. You either set a time in the future, or leave it at zero and the cookie expires when the browser is closed.

Comment: If you set the expire time in the future the cookie will only expire in the future.

Comment: Unix starts time at midnight Jan 1 1970. It looks like you've actually set a value of -1 here. If you use 0, this "Expires / Max-Age" column should show "Session" (or similar) instead of a timestamp.

Comment: It would be useful to see the code you have for setting the cookie expiration time